How can I make DISTINCT and FIRST_VALUE executing faster?
I have the following query:
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(business_id)
       OVER (PARTITION BY b.sub_category_id
             ORDER BY AVG(stars) desc, COUNT(*) DESC) business_id,
       sub_category_id
FROM purchase_experience pe
JOIN businesses b ON b.id = pe.business_id
 AND b.status = 'active'
 AND b.sub_category_id IN (1010 ,1007 ,1034 ,1036)
WHERE pe.stars <> 0
GROUP BY business_id
LIMIT 4

It returns something like this:
business_id | sub_category_id
1744        | 1007
13215       | 1010
9231        | 1034
9103        | 1036

And here is the result of EXPLAIN:

The sad part is, it takes about 7secs to be executed. Any idea how can I make it optimize?

I can't figure out what's going on here. A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY turned off?

This is a typical Top-1-per-group problem.
You can use ROW_NUMBER instead, this will be more efficient than DISTINCT.
SELECT
  b.business_id,
  b.sub_category_id
FROM (
    SELECT
      b.sub_category_id,
      b.id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.sub_category_id
             ORDER BY AVG(stars) desc, COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM purchase_experience pe
    JOIN businesses b ON b.id = pe.business_id
     AND b.status = 'active'
     AND b.sub_category_id IN (1010 ,1007 ,1034 ,1036)
    WHERE pe.stars <> 0
    GROUP BY
      b.sub_category_id,
      b.id
) b
WHERE b.rn = 1
LIMIT 4;

Note that you seem to be missing sub_category_id from your GROUP BY.

It returns the same result, but apparently doesn't make any change in the performance.

You'd need an index businesses (sub_category_id, id, status) and purchase_experience (business_id, stars) but either way the sorting happens after aggregation so you can't speed that up. Try grouping by b.id instead.

Remove DISTINCT, it seems to be trying to do the same thing as FIRST_VALUE.
The query seems to be a "groupwise_max" problem.  See the tag I added for better ways to do that.  Or look here:  Groupwise-Max
irst write the query to find the stats for the whole table, then figure out how to apply the groupwise-max.
Also, with LIMIT 4, which 4 do you want?  You need ORDER BY to specify such.
These may help:
pe: INDEX(business_id, stars)
b:  INDEX(status, sub_category, id)


When I remove DISTINCT the result changes https://i.sstatic.net/eUcW6.png

OK, leave the DISTINCT in and change go GROUP BY 1.  And do add the indexes.

After using GROUP BY 1, it throws: #1056 - Can't group on 'business_id'
